# Subir un archivo a carpeta google drive api php error

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Estoy intentado usar un código para subir un archivo de prueba (en este caso una imagen) y me da error cuando ejecuto el código, no consigo encontrar que esta mal, alguien me puede ayudar??
El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on
> null in archivo.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in archivo.php on
> line 24"

La linea 24 es la línea de '$resultado = $service->files->create($file);'

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=archivo.json');

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']);

try {

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($client);
    $file_path = "test.png";

    $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName($file_path);

    $file->setParents(["id_carpeta"]);
    $file->setDescription("Archivo de prueba");
    $file->setMimeType("image/png");

    $resultado = $service->files->create($file);
    echo '<a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=' . $resultado->id . '"target="_blank">'.$resultado->name.'</a>';
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $gs) {
    $mensaje = json_decode($gs->getMessage());
    echo $mensaje->error->message();
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Por lo que me parece ver por [aqui](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive.html#$files) diría que lo que necesitas es esto: `$service = new Google_Service_Drive();` en lugar de esto: `$service = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($client);` para poder usar el `$service->files`

Comment: Parece que el servicio no se está creando correctamente y esto puede deberse a muchos motivos. Dinos si ya autorizaste el proyecto en GCP, si el archivo `.json` descargado con las credenciales está en el lugar correcto, si en el proyecto autorizaste la API de Google Drive. Dinos si hay más errores en el log de errores de PHP. Dinos qué tipo de servicio has configurado en GCP, etc. Falta información en tu pregunta.